# Trouble with delimiter

Tags: python

I want to use a '.' as a delimiter, but I get an "IndexError: list index out of range" error with the code below. If I remove the delimiter portion, the code works as I want it to. Any idea why this? Many thanks in advance.

```
import csv

mags = csv.reader(open("mags.csv","rU"), delimiter='.')

for row in mags:

     print [item.lower() for item in [row[index] for index in (1, 0)]]
```

Comment: can you please post a few sample lines?

Comment: as @cherhan said, post some sample lines. A part from that there seems to be a problem with your loop rather than the delimiter '.'

Comment: Here are a few sample lines if I remove the delimiter altogether: ['tom', 'smith']
['ben', 'cohen']
['scott', 'friedman']
['michael', 'jones']

Comment: Where is the '.' delimiter in that output?  Are you sure that your input has '.' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is a line that is missing the `.` delimiter.

To see what *csv.reader* is doing, add `print repr(row)` just before the other print-statement.  That will probably reveal a line that was parsed into only zero or one fields.

If the data actually had a `.` delimiter in every row, your code would work fine:

```
>>> txt = '''\
tom.smith
ben.cohen
scott.friedman
michael.jones
'''.splitlines()
>>> import csv
>>> for row in csv.reader(txt, delimiter='.'):
        print [item.lower() for item in [row[index] for index in (1, 0)]]

['smith', 'tom']
['cohen', 'ben']
['friedman', 'scott']
['jones', 'michael']
```

It could be that your input data has commas for delimiters and that you want a different delimiter for the output.  Here's how:

```
>>> txt = '''\
tom,smith
ben,cohen
scott,friedman
michael,jones
'''.splitlines()
>>> for row in csv.reader(txt):
        print '.'.join([item.lower() for item in [row[index] for index in (1, 0)]])

smith.tom
cohen.ben
friedman.scott
jones.michael
```

Comment: The sample lines I showed in my previous comment are the result of running the code WITHOUT the delimiter. If I run the code as it appears in my original question, that's when I get the "out of range IndexError". Make sense?

Comment: @mantissa45 could you please show us your csv file? If it works without the '.' as delimiter, then it looks like your csv is not separated by '.'

Comment: @marcocamejo: you're correct; the contents of the CSV are not separated by '.' They are just names and magazine titles across 10 rows. What's the best way to share the actual CSV?

Comment: @mantissa45 Your input is missing the '.' delimiter.  It has a comma instead.  That is why you only get one field when you set the delimiter to a period.  To fix it, use input data that has periods in it (as shown in the answer).  Your code is fine. You're problem is with your data which doesn't have periods on every row.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: Thanks! Would this be the way to do it if the CSV contained hundreds of names instead of only 10? I imagine there would be a more efficient way of handling a CSV of that magnitude, correct?

Comment: This would work fine for large csv files.  The *csv module* is written in C, so it is fast.  The same is true for *str.join*.  That being said, this is an IO bound process, so the kind of code you use won't make much difference in the overall running time.